# Issue with loop in trading strategy backtest

Tags: loops, finance, stock, arima, yfinance

I'm currently trying to put together some code that backtests a simple trading strategy involving sequencing through time series price data, incrementally fitting an ARIMA model, making future price predictions, and then either adding a share if the price is predicted to increase, or selling all accumulated shares if the price is predicted to go down. Currently, it's returning nan values for the projected returns from trades and appears to only be selling somehow.

I've attached my code below. There's just a few simple functions for calculating a sharpe ratio and then the main function for running backtests.

```
import yfinance as yf
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_acf, plot_pacf
from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from tqdm import tqdm
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.tools.sm_exceptions import ValueWarning, HessianInversionWarning, ConvergenceWarning
import warnings

#in practice do not supress these warnings, they carry important information about the status of your model
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category=ValueWarning)
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category=HessianInversionWarning)
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category=ConvergenceWarning)

tickerSymbol = 'SPY'
data = yf.Ticker(tickerSymbol)

prices = data.history(start='2017-01-01', end='2019-01-01').Close
returns = prices.pct_change().dropna()

def std_dev(data):
    # Get number of observations
    n = len(data)
    # Calculate mean
    mean = sum(data) / n
    # Calculate deviations from the mean
    deviations = sum([(x - mean)**2 for x in data])
    # Calculate Variance & Standard Deviation
    variance = deviations / (n - 1)
    s = variance**(1/2)
    return s

# Sharpe Ratio From Scratch
def sharpe_ratio(data, risk_free_rate=0):
    # Calculate Average Daily Return
    mean_daily_return = sum(data) / len(data)
    print(f"mean daily return = {mean_daily_return}")
    # Calculate Standard Deviation
    s = std_dev(data)
    # Calculate Daily Sharpe Ratio
    daily_sharpe_ratio = (mean_daily_return - risk_free_rate) / s
    # Annualize Daily Sharpe Ratio
    sharpe_ratio = 252**(1/2) * daily_sharpe_ratio
    return sharpe_ratio

def run_simulation(returns, prices, amt, order, thresh, verbose=True, plot=True):
    if type(order) == float:
        thresh = None
        

    sum_list = []
    events_list = []
    sharpe_list = []
    init_amt = amt

    #go through dates
    for date, r in tqdm (returns.iloc[14:].items(), total=len(returns.iloc[14:])):
        #if you're currently holding the stock, sell it
        

        #get data til just before current date
        curr_data = returns[:date]
        
        if type(order) == tuple:
            try:
                #fit model
                model = ARIMA(curr_data, order=order).fit(maxiter=200)

                #get forecast
                pred = model.forecast()[0][0]

            except:
                pred = thresh - 1


        #if you predict a high enough return and not holding, buy stock
        if ((type(order) == float and np.random.random() < order) 
         or (type(order) == tuple and pred > thresh)):
        
            
           
            buy_price = prices.loc[date]
            events_list.append(('b', date))
            int_buy_price = int(buy_price)
            sum_list.append(int_buy_price)
            if verbose:
                print('Bought at $%s'%buy_price)
                print('Predicted Return: %s'%round(pred,4))
                print('Actual Return: %s'%(round(ret, 4)))
                print('=======================================')
            continue

        #if you predict below the threshold return, sell the stock
        if ((type(order) == float and np.random.random() < order) 
         or (type(order) == tuple and thresh > pred)
         or (order == 'last' and curr_data[-1] > 0)):
            
            sell_price = prices.loc[date]
            
            total_return = len(sum_list) * sell_price 

            ret = (total_return-sum(sum_list))/sum(sum_list)
            amt *= (1+ret)
            events_list.append(('s', date, ret))
            sharpe_list.append(ret)
            sum_list.clear()

            if verbose:
                print('Sold at $%s'%sell_price)
                print('Predicted Return: %s'%round(pred,4))
                print('Actual Return: %s'%(round(ret, 4)))
                print('=======================================')
            

                
    if verbose:
        sharpe = sharpe_ratio(sharpe_list, risk_free_rate=0)
        print('Total Amount: $%s'%round(amt,2))
        print(f"Sharpe Ratio: {sharpe}")
        
    #graph
    if plot:
    
        plt.figure(figsize=(10,4))
        plt.plot(prices[14:])

        y_lims = (int(prices.min()*.95), int(prices.max()*1.05))
        shaded_y_lims = int(prices.min()*.5), int(prices.max()*1.5)

        for idx, event in enumerate(events_list):
            plt.axvline(event[1], color='k', linestyle='--', alpha=0.4)
            if event[0] == 's':
                color = 'green' if event[2] > 0 else 'red'
                plt.fill_betweenx(range(*shaded_y_lims), 
                                  event[1], events_list[idx-1][1], color=color, alpha=0.1)

        tot_return = round(100*(amt / init_amt - 1), 2)
        sharpe = sharpe_ratio(sharpe_list, risk_free_rate=0)
        tot_return = str(tot_return) + '%'
        plt.title("%s Price Data\nThresh=%s\nTotal Amt: $%s\nTotal Return: %s"%(tickerSymbol, thresh, round(amt,2), tot_return), fontsize=20)
        plt.ylim(*y_lims)
        plt.show()
        print(sharpe)
    
    return amt

# A model with a dth difference to fit and ARMA(p,q) model is called an ARIMA process 
# of order (p,d,q). You can select p,d, and q with a wide range of methods, 
# including AIC, BIC, and empirical autocorrelations (Petris, 2009).


for thresh in [0.001]:
    run_simulation(returns, prices, 100000, (7,1,7), thresh, verbose=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered that it's failing to fit the ARIMA model for some reason. Not converging to a solution, I guess. I'm not sure why though because it was fitting it just fine when I was running a different strategy using the same data and order.